# Jquery auto-suggest from database table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, json

What are the steps to creating an auto-suggest text field that grabs for instance `usernames` from my database?

I plan to use the Jquery UI [autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default). The goal is to have a quick and very secure method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial should help: http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/